# Android Gradient - meaning of attributes

Tags: android, attributes, gradient

For the `<gradient>` in Android, I cannot understand the meaning of the `centerX` and `centerY` attributes and how their values affect the shape.
Also what is the meaning of the gradient type `sweep` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:centerX` and `android:centerY` default values are 0.5.

0.5 is the center of the view, their range of values are from 0 to 1, being centerX=centerY=0 the upper-left corner of the screen and centerX=centerY=1 the bottom-right corner if the view fills the screen.

Sweep is a kind of circular gradient. Imagine a wide paint brush were one of the sides is sticked and you make a complete circular movement. The effect is like a conic looked from above.